# Leaflet geoman : draw rectangle with long click

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, leaflet-geoman

i am using the plugin Geoman-io from leaflet to draw some rectangle onto a map.
It's working perfectly.

But i would like to be able to draw a rectangle with on long hold click instead of two click.

**Current behavior**: select rectangle form -> user must click on the map -> move the mouse somewhere -> click again to finish the rectangle.

**What i want** : select rectangle form -> user must click on the map and hold -> move the mouse somewhere -> release the click

I could not find any information to do so in the documentation/api.

Thank you

**EDIT: I found my response : https://github.com/geoman-io/leaflet-geoman/issues/1106 . It is not yet implemented but it is in features request.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found my response : https://github.com/geoman-io/leaflet-geoman/issues/1106 . It is not yet implemented but it is in features request.**